# Magento 2 - How to create invoice using custom rest API?

Tags: magento2, rest-api, create-invoice

I am trying to create invoice using customer token. But getting following error.

```
No such entity with orderId = 31
```

This error is generated after execution of following code.

```
$transactionSave = $this->_transaction->addObject(
                    $invoice
                )->addObject(
                    $order
                );
$transactionSave->save(); //This statement causes error
```

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

hi Please try below code for generate Invoice programatically

```
        $orderId = 31; //order id for which want to create invoice
        $order = $this->_orderRepository->get($orderId);
        if($order->canInvoice()) {
            $itemsArray = ['80'=>2]; //here 80 is order item id and 2 is it's quantity to be invoice
            $shippingAmount = '10.00';
            $subTotal = '110.00';
            $baseSubtotal = '110.00';
            $grandTotal = '110.00';
            $baseGrandTotal = '110.00';
            $invoice = $this->_invoiceService->prepareInvoice($order, $itemsArray);
            $invoice->setShippingAmount($shippingAmount);
            $invoice->setSubtotal($subTotal);
            $invoice->setBaseSubtotal($baseSubtotal);
            $invoice->setGrandTotal($grandTotal);
            $invoice->setBaseGrandTotal($baseGrandTotal);
            $invoice->register();
            $transactionSave = $this->_transaction->addObject(
                $invoice
            )->addObject(
                $invoice->getOrder()
            );
            $transactionSave->save();
            $this->invoiceSender->send($invoice);   
            //send notification code
            $order->addStatusHistoryComment(
                __('Notified customer about invoice #%1.', $invoice->getId())
            )
            ->setIsCustomerNotified(true)
            ->save();
```

Please refer below link for that :- https://webkul.com/blog/how-to-programmatically-create-invoice-in-magento2/

Answer (score 0):

There is a default Magento REST API available to create shipment/invoice for the order.
You can use it as follows.

```
POST to URL 
https://vaseemansari.com/rest/V1/order/order_id/invoice
https://vaseemansari.com/rest/V1/order/1199305/invoice


Body 
{
    "capture": true,
    "items": [
        {
            "extension_attributes": {},
            "order_item_id": 2679144,   // This is the sales_order_item ID
            "qty": 1
        }
    ],
    "appendComment": true,
    "comment": {
        "extension_attributes": {},
        "comment": "Order Invoice generated via REST API",
        "is_visible_on_front": 0
    },
    "arguments": {
        "extension_attributes": {}
    },
    "notify": false
}
```

Or you can try this CURL as well

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://vaseemansari.com/rest/V1/order/1199305/invoice' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--header 'Authorization: Bearer bobkb32j4uv5ym3px6nfjkg5jzmoy7cc' \
--header 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=kafslfq30gv0gf7uptb92rjmnf; PHPSESSID=kafslfq30gv0gf7uptb92rjmnf; form_key=OOuH11iCJ3nLS7qS; persistent_shopping_cart=OWDN0gl7nnrU8lGZPHG2cFhzd6xS57WIwDY5zvJIwsMkvWeobu; private_content_version=9f66c6ed545f829348df1e1d26bcf368' \
--data-raw '{
    "capture": true,
    "items": [
        {
            "extension_attributes": {},
            "order_item_id": 2679144,
            "qty": 1
        }
    ],
    "appendComment": true,
    "comment": {
        "extension_attributes": {},
        "comment": "Order Invoice generated via REST API",
        "is_visible_on_front": 0
    },
    "arguments": {
        "extension_attributes": {}
    },
    "notify": false
}'
```